# select rows with same ID and select remaining row without same ID

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, select

I need to select rows with common IDs first, then the remaining rows without the common id (no repeats.)

This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.cars,b.wheels,c.glass
FROM table auto a, tires b, window c
WHERE a.ID = b.ID AND c.ID = a.ID
????AND/OR a.ID <> b.ID????
```

<--lastly select rows where A and B do not have common ID's but with no duplicate records

**Auto**

```
id cars
1   data
2   data
3   data
4   data
```

**Tires**

```
id wheels
1   data
2   data
5   data  <-- ID different from table 'Auto' but still want to select it
9   data  <-- ID different from table 'Auto' but still want to select it
200 data  <-- ID different from table 'Auto' but still want to select it
```

**Window**

```
id glass
1  data
2  data
3  data
4  data
```

Comment: You need to show us some **table structures** and sample data, and explain more clearly what it is you're trying to achieve here....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a LEFT JOIN, instead of the implicit INNER JOIN you have via the WHERE clause, will return both matching and unmatched rows from the `auto` table.

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.cars, b.wheels, c.glass
    FROM auto a
        LEFT JOIN tires b
            ON a.id = b.id
        LEFT JOIN window c
            ON a.id = c.id
    ORDER BY a.cars, b.wheels, c.glass
```

Comment: Gosh - how are you able to figure out *what this question* really is all about!!?!? I admire your talent.... :-)

Comment: @marc_s: Years of practice turning user requirement documents into functional code. :-)

Comment: As Joe has shown, it's always a good idea to explicitly declare your JOINs.  This helps prevent any ambiguity and protects you from doing a Cartesian join (in the event that you mess-up your WHERE clause).